# Can I override the behavior of the assignment operator?

Tags: ruby

My game development framework has a `Point` class (stores `x`, `y` coordinates and other useful things). My game objects have a `@position` property, which is a `Point` instance. When `@position` is modified, the game object will be drawn somewhere else.

My problem is this:

```
@someSprite.position = Point.new(100,100)
temp = @someSprite.position
temp.x = 500
```

`temp` becomes a reference of `@someSprite.position`. Modifying it would also change the sprite's position. This is something I don't want. I want `temp` to be a different instance.

I can't do something like this:

```
temp = @someSprite.position.clone
```

because of another detail in the framework: `Point` is [observable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). `@someSprite` is observing its own property, `@someSprite.position`.

If I use `clone`, then `temp` would also clone the observer registry. And when `temp`'s state changes, `@someSprite` will be notified, creating a mess.

One could do this then:

```
temp = @someSprite.position.clone
temp.remove_observer(@someSprite)
```

But that feels unpractical and hackish.

Another approach would be:

```
temp = Point.new(@someSprite.position)
```

where I make a constructor for `Point` where it takes the values from another `Point` (without copying the observer registry). This sounds like the best approach so far, but what I want to achieve is

```
temp = @someSprite.position
```

Can this be done? Can I override the behavior of the assignment operator in this case?

Comment: The assignment operator is *never* overridable in Ruby. Setters are setters; even hiding behind sugar that make them appear to use the assignment operator (they do not really as setter calls are really dispatched messages).

Comment: @user2246674: How about suggesting a practical solution instead of just being rude?

Comment: @user2246674: Could you expand on your mutability idea in an answer? I'm curious, but frankly I'm still missing the suggestion.

Comment: @Omega I like the last approach (or to override clone or add a similar method so as to not return any extra information like attached observables). Document the behavior; there is no way to change the behavior of an assignment. My previously (now deleted) comment about having two separate types is likely too complex. I do, still, however, encourage striving for immutability - however, immutability and observables are fairly opposing approaches.

Comment: It looks to me like you should have a `Position` class that has a `Point` and an observer. Then it is straightforward: `temp = @someSprite.position` just copies the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your are using `attr_reader` on `@position` to define the `position` method of the sprite. But you can also define your own getters. In this case I'd suggest you to create an explicit getter for the position:

```
class Sprite
    def position
        return Point.new(@position.x, @position.y)
    end
end
```

It's very rare that you want to have a reference to the position of the sprite inside the object rather than a copy of its value; and it's actually quite dangerous to expose private members of a class.

Comment: Awesome idea. But if I do this, I would be unable to use `@someSprite.position.x = 100` to modify `@someSprite`'s position, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Omega, yes. Why don't you define a `move` (or any other name really) method instead: `@someSprite.move(10, 20)`?

Comment: @Omega, when dealing with game development I usually always create a `move` (offset movement) and a `move_to` (absolute position) method for sprites.

Comment: I see. Well, I guess there's no absolute workaround here, but this is very good either way. Thank you!

Comment: You could just name the non-reference getter differently if you want to be able to choose whether you get a reference or a copy. `position_clone` or something.

Answer (score 1):

You explained why you can't use `clone` however that doesn't mean you can't either override `clone` or create a new method like `duplicate`.

So on your Point class just define:

```
def duplicate
  Point.new(x,y)
end
```

Then you can do:

```
temp = @someSprite.position.duplicate
```

Comment: So would `temp = @someSprite.position` in the way described above not be possible?

Comment: Correct, since temp is just a variable you are assigning a value to, like the original commenter on your question stated, there is nothing to override. If you were for instance setting an attribute on another object like `someOtherObject.point = @someSprite.position` then you could define the `point=` method on the other object to safely clone the position. But that's not what you are doing so the next best thing is to put a method on point that knows how to make a safe copy.

Comment: [`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) or [`clone`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-clone) might be better names since `Object` already supports them.

Comment: Do you mean `Point.new(x, y)`? What you have calls a method `Point` with the args `x` & `y` and then passes its result to a method `new`.

Comment: Good point Andrew, I just finished writing a bunch of Coffeescript before answering that question and had the wrong initializer on my mind.

Comment: And yes, I would just override clone or dup in most cases but I'm not going to recommend to someone they override a method on Object unless I know they know the ramifications. I did put it as a suggestion but use a different method as my answer to play it safe.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is open source, so of course, you can override the assignment operator, with just a little bit of knowledge with the language `C`.  But I would not advise it.